# Why do terminals represent escape as ^[?

Tags: terminal, escaping, pty

As I understand the escape char can be represented in the following ways.

- octal: \033
- hexadecimal: \x1B
- decimal: 27
- unicode: \u001B
- in my terminal: ^[

The first 4 representations are just decimal 27 in varying number systems. But the last representation `^[` doesn't seem to have any link to decimal 27, it seems arbitrary. So I am wondering why `^[` was chosen as the way to represent escape in a terminal, and how that came about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But the last representation `^[` doesn't seem to have any link to decimal 27

It may appear so at first glance, but in reality, there is a link.

First, you need to understand that the caret in notation like `^[` means that the control key is held while pressing <kbd>[</kbd>, so `^[` is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd>. In other words, the escape key acts exactly the same (in a terminal) as <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>[</kbd>. (As to why the escape key produces this particular character: see the second part of my answer.)

The character `[` is encoded in ASCII as decimal 91, or 0x5b, but it's most useful to look at the binary representation: 0b01011011.  `^[`, or the escape key, is encoded as decimal 27, or 0b00011011. If we align these two binary numbers:

```
 [  0b01011011
^[  0b00011011
```

we can see that `^[` is just a `[` with bit 7 cleared. In fact, adding the control key essentially just clears the top three bits of the character code<sup>[1](https://web.archive.org/web/20190401025802/http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/things-every-hacker-once-knew/#_ascii)</sup>.

So the link between `^[` and 27 is that 91 − 64 = 27 :)

---

> why `^[` was chosen as the way to represent escape in a terminal

I have absolutely no idea!